# Equivalent of xpath/xquery as to xml for css?

Tags: css

I want to search for content in a CSS file. The XPath/XQuery language is convenient for searching content in XML. How can I find an equivalent so that complex searches in CSS are easy?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to find info and edit the info in CSS as xpath/xquery for xml.